# unable to open log device(Nexus s miui2.3.7c)

Tags: android, logcat

" unable to open log device" in android development.How to deal with it?

Comment: unable to open log device means what your are doing or looking for

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide some more information to your problem. In what situation are you getting this error message? Is there a stacktrace? If so, please post this as well as relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/steel-droid-d3/193416-logcat-disabled.html#post1968652

if your smartphone is rooted... dont worry if theire istn the same file... in my case it was 07dark_knightweak